# How to parse HCL .tfvars file into a GO struct?

Tags: go, struct, hcl

I have a tfvars file that I want to parse into a go struct. I would like to use go struct later in program like project.config_version and compare the string to something else. variables "project" "tags" "security_groups" and "obs" are type = any

source file:

```
project = {
  config_version         = "0.1.0"
  domain_name            = "something"
  tenant_name            = "example" 
  project_name           = "example" 
  vpc_cidr               = "0.0.0.0./22"

  enable_peering         = true
  peer_tenant_name       = "monitoring" 
  peer_vpc_name          = "vpc-1" 
  service_project_name   = "monitoring" 
  service_project_stage  = "test"      

  enable_frontend_subnet = true
  frontend_subnet_cidr   = "0.0.0.0/24"
  frontend_gateway_ip    = "0.0.0.1"

  security_groups = {
    inbound_ips          = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    port_range_min       = 1
    port_range_max       = 10000
  }

  obs = {
    enable_monitoring    = true
  }
}

tags = {
  Customer               = "example"
}
```

this is what I have tried:

```
package main

import (
    //"fmt"
    "testing"
    "log"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl2/gohcl"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl2/hclparse"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
)



type ObsProject struct{
    Enable_monitoring bool `hcl:"enable_monitoring"`
}

type SecurityGroups struct{
    inbound_ips []string `hcl:"inbound_ips"`
    port_range_min string `hcl:"port_range_min"`
    port_range_max string `hcl:"port_range_max"`
}

type Project struct{
  ConfigVersion string `hcl:"config_version"`
  DomainName string `hcl:"domain_name"`
  TenantName string `hcl:"tenant_name"`
  ProjectName string `hcl:"project_name"`
  VpcCidr string `hcl:"vpc_cidr"`

  EnablePeering bool `hcl:"enable_peering"`
  PeerTenantName string `hcl:"peer_tenant_name"`
  PeerVpcName string `hcl:"peer_vpc_name"`
  ServiceProjectName string `hcl:"service_project_name"`
  ServiceProjectStage string `hcl:"service_project_stage"`      

  EnableFrontendSubnet string `hcl:"enable_frontend_subnet"`
  FrontendSUbnetCidr string `hcl:"frontend_subnet_cidr"`
  FrontendGatewayIP string `hcl:"frontend_gateway_ip"`

  SecurityGroups *SecurityGroups `hcl:"security_groups,block"`

  ObsProject *ObsProject `hcl:"obs,block`
}
type Tags struct {
    Customer string `hcl:"Customer"`
}
type ProjectTfvars struct {
    Project *Project `hcl:"project,block"`
    Tags *Tags `hcl:"tags,block"`
}

func readProjectTfvars(filename string ) (*ProjectTfvars) {
    parser := hclparse.NewParser()
    f, parseDiags := parser.ParseHCLFile(filename)
    if parseDiags.HasErrors() {
    log.Fatal(parseDiags.Error())
    return nil
    }
    
    var projectTfvars ProjectTfvars
    decodeDiags := gohcl.DecodeBody(f.Body, nil, &projectTfvars)
    if decodeDiags.HasErrors() {
    log.Fatal(decodeDiags.Error())
    }
    return &projectTfvars
}
```

error message that I have received:

Unsupported argument; An argument named "tags" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "tags"?, and 1 other diagnostic(s)

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: is this correct: 
`type Tags struct {
    Customer []string `hcl:"Customer"`
}`? In the example Customer is only a string

Comment: you are right , that was not correct